React State Handling
I made a caching method in my react notepad and came up with a minor bug, I used useEffect to set an interval of 3 seconds and then it updates the cache holder if the heading and description are not false although when it starts to run and either of the heading or description changes back to false (empty or invalid value) the interval doesn't recognize the updates
when it starts to run it does not stop even though the heading or description has emptied which has to set the interval condition to false
let [heading, setHeading] = useState(addTextCache.heading)
let [description, setDescription] = useState(addTextCache.description)
useEffect(() => {
    let count = 0
    setInterval(() => {
        if(heading != false && description != false) {
            count++
            console.log(count)
            console.log(heading != false && description != false)
            setAddTextCache({
                heading: heading,
                description: description
            })
      }
    }, 3000)
}, [heading, description])


Issues

The useEffect hook callback has a closure over the heading and description state value from the time the interval(s) is(are) instantiated, so the callback can never see any updated value.
The useEffect hook never cleans up existing intervals when the dependencies update.

Solution Suggestion
Use a React ref to cache the heading and description state values which can be accessed within the interval callback.
const [heading, setHeading] = useState(addTextCache.heading);
const [description, setDescription] = useState(addTextCache.description);

// React refs and useEffect hooks to cache current state values
const headingRef = useRef(heading);
const descriptionRef = useRef(description);

useEffect(() => {
  headingRef.current = heading;
}, [heading]);

useEffect(() => {
  descriptionRef.current = description;
}, [description]);

// Instantiate the interval once on component mount
useEffect(() => {
  const intervalRef = setInterval(() => {
    const heading = headingRef.current;
    const descriptionRef = descriptionRef.current;

    if (heading != false && description != false) {
      setAddTextCache({ heading, description });

      // clear interval once heading and description are truthy
      clearInterval(intervalRef);
    }
  }, 3000);

  // Return cleanup function to clear interval on component unmount
  return () => {
    clearInterval(intervalRef);
  };
}, []);

